# How to integrate netty-socketio and redisson

Tags: netty-socketio

Sending information to a specific client, so the data of the client must be cached in the backend.
I tried to use Redis to solve the problem, but SocketIOClient cannot be serialized.
I am trying to use Redisson to store UUID in Redis, but I created two SocketIOServers, the client connects to one of the servers, the data is not synchronized, and the size of one of the servers is 0.

---

Translated from Google